# Azure SQL Error Retrieving data from shard - Login Failed for User

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2014, stored-functions

I'm trying to do a cross database query but my error suggest's that I can't even connect to my external data source.

My exact error message is the following:

```
Error retrieving data from shard [DataSource=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx Database=CRDMPointOfSale_Configuration].  The    underlying error message received was: 'Login failed for user 'CRDMAdmin'.'.
```

Below is my 'Create Database Scoped Credential'.

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL CRDMCred
WITH IDENTITY = 'CRDMAdmin',
SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
GO
```

Below is my 'Create Extenal Data Source'.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE CRDM_Configuration
 WITH (
 TYPE=RDBMS,
 LOCATION='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
 DATABASE_NAME='CRDMPointOfSale_Configuration',
 CREDENTIAL = CRDMCred
);
```

Below you can see my execute remote statement is within a stored procedure. Which I've seen elsewhere online.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [admin].[InsertThreadProcessingDataIntoLoadTable]
(
  @ThreadID         VARCHAR(100)
, @DataLoadSchemaID INT     OUTPUT
, @DateFrom         CHAR(8) OUTPUT
, @DateTo           CHAR(8) OUTPUT
, @DatabaseName     VARCHAR(100)
)

AS BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @IsBatchLoad BIT

SET @IsBatchLoad = CASE 'NO' WHEN 'YES' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END


Exec  sp_execute_remote @data_source_name = N'CRDM_Configuration',
@stmt = N'SELECT @DateFrom = CONVERT(CHAR(8),FromDate,112), @DateTo =         CONVERT(CHAR(8),DATEADD(DAY,1,ToDate),112)
FROM [admin].[GetFromAndToDatesForDatabase] (@DatabaseName,  @IsBatchLoad,NULL)',
@params = N'@DatabaseName VARCHAR(100), @IsBatchLoad BIT',
@DatabaseName = 'CRDMPointOfSale', @IsBatchLoad = 1;

END
```

As you can see above the execute remote contains a SELECT statement, the FROM  is the result of a function being called ([admin].[GetFromAndToDatesForDatabase]) that is from a different database which is why i have a 'Exec  sp_execute_remote' wrapped around.

Should I be specifying parameters when not directly calling a SP? Also what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Main error message ''Error retrieving data from shard .............  The    underlying error message received was: 'Login failed for user 'CRDMAdmin'." has now been resolved. Issue was the credentials (password) was incorrect.

Comment: Still having trouble with this 'SELECT @DateFrom = CONVERT(CHAR(8),FromDate,112)' part inside the Exec  sp_execute_remote statement